# Standard Error in OLS Regression

Tags: statistics, regression, standard-deviation

Assuming I have the following linear regression set-up:

$y_i = \alpha + x_i * \beta + \epsilon_i$

for $i = 1,2,..., n$.

When I run the regession, I get a $\beta$ and $\alpha$ estimates, along with their standard errors. Let $\sigma_{\alpha}$ and $\sigma_{\beta}$ be the standard error of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively.

If I want to compute the standard error of the expression $\hat{\alpha} + x_i * {\hat\beta}$ for each value of $i$, would that be:

$\sqrt{\sigma^2_{\alpha} + x^2_i * \sigma^2_{\beta}}$   ???

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Well $x_i$ as you said can be treated as a constant. I mean overall standard error. We have the standard error of the two terms, are they additive? Is there a correlation term?

Comment: What would be your suggestion in computing the standard deviation of that quantity?

Comment: Actually, this is not really what I am after. I am looking for the standard error of that specific quantity.

Comment: well you could calculate $var(\hat{\alpha} + x_i \hat{\beta})$ if you knew $E(\hat{\alpha}\hat{\beta})$. You can find formulas for $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$, so perhaps you can calculate this expectation analytically.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps calculating this variance will help

\begin{align}
var(\hat{\alpha} + x_i \hat{\beta})&= var(\hat{\alpha})+x_i^2 var(\hat{\beta}) + 2cov(\hat{\alpha},\hat{\beta}x_i)\\
&= var(\hat{\alpha})+x_i^2 var(\hat{\beta}) + 2x_icov(\hat{\alpha},\hat{\beta})\\
&= var(\hat{\alpha})+x_i^2 var(\hat{\beta}) - 2x_i \frac{\sigma^2\bar{x}}{S_{xx}}
\end{align}

where $\sigma^2=var(\epsilon_i)$. The last line comes from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115011/in-simple-linear-regression-where-does-the-formula-for-the-variance-of-the-resi/115040#115040).  If $\sigma^2$ is unknown, an unbiased estimator for it is

$$\hat{\sigma}^2 = (S_{yy} − \beta S_{xy})/(n − 2)$$

**Sanity check:** Note that the covariance term is negative. This makes sense. In simple linear regression the point $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ is always on the regression line. Now imagine increasing the slope, but fixing $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$, in this case the y intercept would decrease. Therefore, it makes sense that the estimate of the slope and the estimate of the intercept would be negatively correlated.